# Adjusting the handlelength of horizontal lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to adjust the legend of one graph. The values of two groups are represented as bar plots, while the average values of two groups are indicated by horizontal lines. I have a problem of adjusting the handle length of the horizontal line -- handlelength argument does not seem to work here.

As shown in the following graph, the handle is too long for "Population." The code the generated the graph is given below. Would anyone be able to help with this issue?

[image]

```
    n_groups = 5

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))

    index = np.arange(n_groups)
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.4

    means_g1 = np.array([ 7.76349192,  8.1247542 ,  7.49507752,  7.27215192,  5.66707868])
    means_g2 = np.array([ 0.64601404,  0.43165984,  0.87665884,  1.12260548,  1.93469648])


    ax.bar(index, means_g1, bar_width,
                     alpha=opacity,
                     color='b',
                     error_kw=error_config,
                     label='Group 1')

    ax.bar(index + bar_width, means_g2, bar_width,
                     alpha=opacity,
                     color='r',
                     error_kw=error_config,
                     label='Group 2')

    ax.plot(index+bar_width,(means_g1+means_g2)/2,'_',ms=25,mew=1.5,label='Population')

    ax.legend(loc = 0, fancybox = True, framealpha = 0.2, prop={'size':10},
             #handlelength=3
             )

    ax.set_xlabel('Number of states')
    ax.set_xticks(index + bar_width)
    ax.set_xticklabels(('2', '4', '6', '8', '10'))
    ax.set_xlim(-bar_width,5)
    ax.set_ylim([0,10])

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```